# How do I correctly modify my bash script to use for loops?

Tags: linux, bash, ffmpeg, mediainfo

I am rewriting my bash script for transcoding videos using ffmpeg to allow for batch processing instead of individual processing, and having trouble with for loops reading files for metadata. Any assistance would be appreciated.

Basically, I am declaring variables at the top for which gather title, year, folder name, etc. from the file which depending on the movie, is in its own subdirectory of the base directory. That metadata is then used to download a poster image, capture a thumbnail from the file and copy the srt files (for use in a remux script) and two-pass transcode the file into x265, preserving the audio.

```
for f in *.mp4; do
    ## SET LOCAL ROOT PATH ##
    LROOTPATH="/mnt/e/tmp"
    ## SET CLOUD ROOT PATH ##
    CROOTPATH="/mnt/g/Shared drives/flix"
    ## GET TITLE FROM MOVIE FILE USING FILEBOT - DO NOT EDIT ##
    TITLE="$(filebot -mediainfo -r "$f" --format "{media.Title}")"
    ## GET YEAR FROM MOVIE FILE USING FILEBOT - DO NOT EDIT ##
    YEAR="$(filebot -mediainfo -r "$f" --format "{media.Recorded_Date}")"
    ## GET BACKUP MOVIE DIRECTORY FROM MOVIE FILE USING FILEBOT - DO NOT EDIT ##
    BMDIR="$(filebot -mediainfo -r "$f" --format "{folder.name}")"
    ## GET BACKUP MOVIE FILE NAME FROM MOVIE FILE USING FILEBOT - DO NOT EDIT ##
    BMFILE="$(filebot -mediainfo -r "$f" --format "{media.Title}")"
    ## PROMPT USER TO ENTER POSTER NAME FROM THEMOVIEDB.ORG MOVIE POSTER PAGE - DO NOT EDIT ##
    echo "Enter file name for ${TITLE} (${YEAR}) movie poster from themoviedb.org:" && read CFILE
    ## SET BACKUP COVER FILE NAME - DO NOT EDIT ##
    BCFILE="${CFILE}"
    ## SET BACKUP DEFAULT SUBTITLE FILE NAME - DO NOT EDIT ##
    BSFILE="${TITLE}.eng.srt"
    ## SET REMUX MOVIE DIRECTORY NAME - DO NOT EDIT ##
    RMDIR="${TITLE} (${YEAR})"
    ## SET REMUX MOVIE FILE NAME - DO NOT EDIT ##
    RMFILE="${TITLE} (${YEAR})"
    ## SET REMUX COVER FILE NAME - DO NOT EDIT ##
    RCFILE="cover"
    ## SET REMUX THUMBNAIL FILE NAME - DO NOT EDIT ##
    RTFILE="thumb"
    ## SET REMUX SUBTITLE FILE NAME - DO NOT EDIT ##
    RSFILE="${RMFILE}.eng.default"
    ## SET LOCAL BACKUP PATH - DO NOT EDIT ##
    LBPATH="${LROOTPATH}/backup/movies/downloaded/${BMDIR}"
    ## SET LOCAL BACKUP FULL PATH - DO NOT EDIT ##
    LBFPATH="${LBPATH}"
    ## SET LOCAL BACKUP MOVIE FILE PATH - DO NOT EDIT ##
    LBMFPATH="${LBFPATH}/${BMFILE}.mp4"
    ## SET LOCAL BACKUP SUBTITLE FILE PATH - DO NOT EDIT ##
    LBSFPATH="${LBFPATH}/${BSFILE}.srt"
    ## SET LOCAL REMUX PATH - DO NOT EDIT ##
    LRPATH="${LROOTPATH}/remux/movies/$(filebot -mediainfo -r "${LBMFPATH}" --format "{HD.lower()}")"
    ## SET LOCAL REMUX FULL PATH - DO NOT EDIT ##
    LRFPATH="${LRPATH}/${RMDIR}"
    ## SET LOCAL REMUX MOVIE FILE PATH - DO NOT EDIT ##
    LRMFPATH="${LRFPATH}/${RMFILE}.mp4"
    ## SET LOCAL REMUX COVER FILE PATH - DO NOT EDIT ##
    LRCFPATH="${LRFPATH}/${RCFILE}.jpg"
    ## SET LOCAL REMUX THUMBNAIL FILE PATH - DO NOT EDIT ##
    LRTFPATH="${LRFPATH}/${RTFILE}.jpg"
    ## SET LOCAL REMUX SUBTITLE FILE PATH - DO NOT EDIT ##
    LRSFPATH="${LRFPATH}/${RSFILE}.srt"
    ## SET CLOUD BACKUP PATH - DO NOT EDIT ##
    CBPATH="${CROOTPATH}/backup/movies"
    ## SET CLOUD BACKUP FULL PATH - DO NOT EDIT ##
    CBFPATH="${CBPATH}"
    ## SET CLOUD BACKUP MOVIE FILE PATH - DO NOT EDIT ##
    CBMFPATH="${CBFPATH}/${BMFILE}.mp4"
    ## SET POSTER URL FROM THEMOVIEDB.ORG MOVIE POSTER PAGE - DO NOT EDIT ##
    TMDB="https://www.themoviedb.org/t/p/original/${CFILE}.jpg"
    ## SET MOVIE ID FROM FANART.TV MOVIE POSTER PAGE (FOR FUTURE USE) - DO NOT EDIT ##
    ## FAMID=""
    ## SET MOVIE POSTER FILE NAME FROM FANART.TV MOVIE POSTER PAGE (FOR FUTURE USE) - DO NOT EDIT ##
    ## FACFILE="${CFILE}"
    ## SET POSTER URL FROM FANART.TV MOVIE POSTER PAGE (FOR FUTURE USE) - DO NOT EDIT ##
    ## FANART="https://fanart.tv/fanart/movies/${FAMID}/movieposter/${FACFILE}.jpg"
    ## CREATE LOCAL RM FULL PATH - DO NOT EDIT ##
    mkdir -v "${LRFPATH}"
    ## DOWNLOAD POSTER FROM THEMOVIEDB.ORG - DO NOT EDIT ##
    wget -O "${LRCFPATH}" https://www.themoviedb.org/t/p/original/${BCFILE}.jpg
    ## cd "${LBFPATH}"
    ## COPY LOCAL BACKUP DEFAULT SUBTITLE FILE PATH TO LOCAL REMUX SUBTITLE FILE PATH - DO NOT EDIT ##
    if [ -f "${LBSDFPATH}" ]; then \
        cp -v "${LBSDFPATH}" "${LRSDFPATH}" \
    fi
    ## COPY LOCAL BACKUP DEFAULT SUBTITLE FILE PATH TO LOCAL REMUX SUBTITLE FILE PATH - DO NOT EDIT ##
    if [ -f "${LBSFFPATH}" ]; then \
        cp -v "${LBSFFPATH}" "${LRSFFPATH}" \
    fi
    do
    ## EXTRACT THUMBNAIL FROM MOVIE FILE USING FFMPEG - DO NOT EDIT ##
    for i in *.mp4; do
        ffmpeg -y -hide_banner \
            -ss 00:10:00 \
            -i "$i" \
            -vframes 1 \
            -q:v 3 \
            -an \
            -metadata:s:t:0 mimetype=image/jpeg \
            -metadata:s:t:0 title="thumb" \
            -threads 16 \
        "${LRTFPATH}"
    done
    for i in *.mp4; do
        ## FIRST PASS OF TWO-PASS x265/HEVC TRANSCODE USING FFMPEG - DO NOT EDIT ##
        ffmpeg -y -hide_banner \
            -i "$i" \
            -pix_fmt yuv420p \
            -c:v libx265 \
            -pass 1 \
            -an \
            -x265-params crf=28 \
            -passlogfile "${LBFPATH}/ffmpeg2pass" \
            -f null \
            -threads 16 \
        /dev/null && \
        ## SECOND PASS OF TWO-PASS x265/HEVC TRANSCODE USING FFMPEG - DO NOT EDIT ##
        ffmpeg -y -hide_banner \
            -i "$i" \
            -pix_fmt yuv420p \
            -c:v libx265 \
            -map 0:v:0 \
            -map 0:a:0 \
            -c:a copy \
            -x265-params crf=28 \
            -pass 2 \
            -threads 16 \
        "${LRMFPATH}"
    done
        ## REMOVE LOCAL BACKUP FULL PATH - DO NOT EDIT (CAN BE COMMENTED OUT/UNCOMMENTED IF REQUIRED) ##
        rm -Rv "${LBFPATH}"
        ## REMOVE LOCAL BACKUP FULL PATH - DO NOT EDIT (CAN BE UNCOMMENTED/COMMENTED OUT IF REQUIRED) ##
        #mv -v "${LBFPATH}" "${CBFPATH}"
done
```

Comment: Please add a suitable shebang (`#!/bin/bash`) and then paste your script at http://www.shellcheck.net/ and try to implement the recommendations made there.

Comment: Please use lowercase variable names only. Otherwise you may clash with environment variables and set or reset them by mistake.

Comment: Also, your nested `for`-cycles (why are they nested?) are a quadratic complexity bomb. With (e.g.) n = 1000 files in the directory there would be 2n² (2000000) `ffmpeg` runs. How could that possibly make sense?

Comment: I'm trying to get the `title`, `year`, `bmdir` and `bmfile` to read the `$f` (file) metadata rather than having to run the bash from the specific backup movie directory. I was initially only running the bash from a specific movie directory and only processing one movie at a time by hardcoding the paths in each variable and input/output parts of ffmpeg,